Issue with calling parent method of Python subclass?
import abc
class Parent(abc.ABC):
 
   def is_valid(self, thing):
      return thing is not None

class Child(Parent):
   def is_valid(self, thing):
      return super(Parent, self).is_valid(thing) and thing > 5

a = Child()
print(a.is_valid(6))

this gives AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'is_valid'
What am I doing wrong?

Did you mean: super().is_valid(thing)?

What are you trying to do with super(Parent, self)? That should either be just Parent or super() (or super(Child, self) for Python 2)

Let's not even bother talking about Python 2.

The first argument to super tells the attribute lookup to start with the class after that argument in the method resolution order (MRO). You don't need any arguments to super at all:
class Child(Parent):
   def is_valid(self, thing):
      return super().is_valid(thing) and thing > 5

but if you want to supply them, the correct first argument is Child, not Parent.
class Child(Parent):
   def is_valid(self, thing):
      return super(Child, self).is_valid(thing) and thing > 5

By specifying Parent as the first argument, you are asking for an is_valid attribute from either abc.ABC or object, neither of which has that attribute.
>>> Child.mro()
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'object'>]

